# Match and retrieve values from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA so not sure where to start with this one. I have two separate workbooks saved in the same file location (Workbook 1 and Workbook 2)

what i'm looking for is When column C is populated in workbook 1, I want a macro that searches for that number in workbook 2 (column A).

If a match is found then I want the corresponding values from column C, D, E and G in Workbook 2 to be copied onto workbook 1.
[Here is the values populated in Workbook1, then matched in Workbook2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzMoD.png)[Here is the expected results, with the matched values populating Workbook1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmE0B.png)

Workbook 2 won't be opened by the user, they will just click a button in Workbook1 and it will populate the data.

I currently have this working but with Vlookups which has greatly slowed down opening workbook 1.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: go for `INDEX/MATCH` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into the Code of the Sheet you are using in File1 and edit the Sheetnames and the Path. You dont need to press a button or anything, the macro will activate if the data in Column C changes and load the data of File2 into File1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim Sheet1, Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim CellChanged As Integer
Dim Path, File As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\2.xlsx" 'Edit Path File2
File = Right$(Path, Len(Path) - InStrRev(Path, "\"))

Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1") 'Edit Sheet File1

Set KeyCells = Range("C:C")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

   CellChanged = Target.Row

   Workbooks.Open (Path)
   Set Sheet2 = Workbooks(File).Worksheets("Tabelle1") 'Edit Sheet of File2

   LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Sheet1.Range("C" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("A" & i) Then
            Sheet1.Range("D" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value 'Date
            Sheet1.Range("E" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value 'Amount
            Sheet1.Range("F" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value 'Payee
            Sheet1.Range("G" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value 'Pol Number
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Workbooks(File).Close savechanges:=False
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: 
Macro to start with a button with multiple edits (last cell change store in H1). Also added an Error handle.

```
Sub WithButton()
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim Sheet1, Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim CellChanged As Integer
Dim Path, File As String
Dim LastRow, LastData As Long
Dim Found As Boolean

On Error GoTo Handle

            Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1") 'Edit Sheet File1

            If Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = "" Then
    Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = 0
    CellChanged = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
End If

If Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row > Sheet1.Range("H1").Value Then
    Path = "C:\Users\L4R21D\Desktop\2.xlsx" 'Edit Path File2
    File = Right$(Path, Len(Path) - InStrRev(Path, "\"))

    CellChanged = Sheet1.Range("H1").Value + 1
    Workbooks.Open(Path)
            Set Sheet2 = Workbooks(File).Worksheets("Tabelle1") 'Edit Sheet of File2

               LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastData = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Sheet1.Range("C" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("A" & i) Then
            Sheet1.Range("D" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value
            Sheet1.Range("E" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value
            Sheet1.Range("F" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value
            Sheet1.Range("G" & CellChanged).Value = Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value
            Found = True
        End If
        If Found = True Or i = LastRow Then
            If CellChanged = LastData Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Found = True Then
                Found = False
                CellChanged = CellChanged + 1
            End If
            i = 0
        End If
    Next i
    Workbooks(File).Close savechanges:=False
                Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = CellChanged
End If
Exit Sub
Handle:
    MsgBox("Error")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that did the job nicely. can this be associated to a command button? trying to see if its more suitable to create multiple entries before triggering the lookup.

Comment: I added a macro that you can call with a button, i store the value of the last cell changed in h1, so it doesnt update every row. u can set the store value to another column u dont need and just hide it. Also please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The button driven answer is amazing and both of your answers were godsends!  I have written one program in python and this is my first foray into VB, and your support helped immensely!  One thing that I think could be improved on with the button driven answer, is that if there is something in column C on sheet 1 that is not a match the program failed; I added a line to iterate CellChanged + 1 if there was not a match on Sheet 1:

```
        If Found = True Then
            Found = False
            CellChanged = CellChanged + 1
        **Else
            CellChanged = CellChanged + 1**
        End If
```